# Error while updatin app from Angular 8 to Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular9

[image]

This error is coming while i am updating my app from angular 8 to angular 9 on run time.

> Error: - Unhandled Promise rejection: R3InjectorError[MatCommonModule
>   -> HighContrastModeDetector -> HighContrastModeDetector -> HighContrastModeDetector]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for
>   HighContrastModeDetector! ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>   NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[MatCommonModule ->
>   HighContrastModeDetector -> HighContrastModeDetector ->
>   HighContrastModeDetector]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for
>   HighContrastModeDetector! Error:- core.js:41544 Uncaught Error: A
>   platform with a different configuration has been created. Please
>   destroy it first.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^2.6.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.32",
    "angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-web-storage": "^7.0.0-beta.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsplumb": "^2.12.9",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-panzoom": "^2.2.2",
    "ng7-dynamic-breadcrumb": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-cacheable": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.27",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
```

Comment: Add the steps you have followed to migrate. Also you can get more information of migration from https://update.angular.io/

Comment: I followed the same step as mentioned in update.angular.io

Comment: ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8 
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
ng update @angular/material
also updated @angular cdk 
delete node_nodule then npm install 
npm start

Comment: did you first updated your angular cli ? required sudo if needed
npm i -g @angular/cli@latest